# c# returning table from pl\sql function

Tags: c#, plsql

So,  i have a function (that i can't change), that returns table of objects, and i need to get them in c# code.

```
create or replace FUNCTION choose_name( )

  RETURN  TBL_names IS
      result TBL_names:=TBL_names();

   /*
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_names as object (
    "Param1" varchar2(555),
    "Param2" NUMBER
    )
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TBL_names is table of OBJ_names
    */
```

And here is a c# code for this:

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "choose_name";
command.Parameters.Add("TBL_names", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

But i 'm getting an error - `wrong types of arguments.` I understand that it is a table, not a ref cursor. How am I suppose to accomplish that?

Comment: btw it's best to leave type attribute names case-insensitive by defining them without double-quotes. Once you name something `"Param1"` (in double-quotes) then everyone who ever refers to it, ever, has to use `"Param1"`, quotes and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion to query table functions, is by treating them like regular SQL:

```
select * from table(choose_name)
```

That will yield rows like you are used to when using `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: I dont like this idea, it's better for me to turn the tableinto a refcursor and read it . but i didnt manage to do it right way

Comment: You are free to do that, but my 2 cents are that the ADO.NET provider from Oracle isn't that good, so I always like to keep it as straightforward as possible.